# ASP.NET MVC Html.Editor pass model to Editor Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Editor Template called "Address.cshtml" that has a model defined as:

```
@model Acme.Models.Address
```

In a View I want call the Editor Template and pass a local variable of the same type, and define the name it will use for the variables, I've tried a number of things including:

```
@Html.Editor("address", "Address", new { Model = address })
```

How do I pass the model?

Note, I cannot use @Html.EditorFor() because the view uses a different model.

Comment: You can still use EditorFor what I see

Comment: @EhsanSajjad how? When you reference the model it in the linq expression it is bound to the view's model, how do you override it to use a different object as the model?

Comment: You can do like `EditorFor(x=> address)` if address is variable in view it should work , but I m not sure , technically it should work

Comment: No, what it does is grabs the type of your variable, and if matches the template, then it just shows the View model property. You can see this when you hover over x  because shows the name of the view's model.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do.  Whenever you try to go against the grain of a framework, you should really consider WHY you want to do this.. chances are, you probably misunderstand what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *only* purpose of `EditorFor` is to work with your view's model. If you need to work with a completely different class instance that's not your view's model or accessible through you're view's model. Then just use `Html.Partial`. They're functionally the same. If you're worried about using a specific editor template, you can always pass the full path to the view to `Html.Partial`.

Comment: Ended up using a Html.Partial. I didn't think EditorFor could be used for this, but I thought there might be a way to use Html.Editor() to pass an object that was the model for the Editor Template.

Comment: @Josh, `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Address)` does pass the object to the `EditorTemplate` (assuming property `Address` is type of `Acme.Models.Address`)

Answer (score 0):

In a view (in its header or somewhere else, but before the row you are calling your Html.Editor) you can add the model in the ViewData with the key equals to your Html.Editor's expression and it will be used as a model in your called editor. For example:

```
@{
    var address = new Acme.Models.Address();
    ViewData["address] = address;
}

@Html.Editor("address", "Address")
```